# Lost focus of the application selected through Mission Control

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control, application-switcher

This problem has been around for at least a year on multiple Sierra versions.

When I’m switching to another app through Mission Control it focuses on that app only for a split of a second and then switches focus to another app. Here’s the video showing the issue (it switches back to Evernote.app despite clicking on the Finder.app):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ustogynwyeu12w4/scr_focus_lost.mov?dl=0

It seems that the app that is set to be visible on All Desktops loses focus if you are switching from an app that has been set to *some* Desktop (Desktop on Display 1, 2, etc.).

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Just clarifying, are you saying you've had this problem since macOS Sierra, or also beforehand? I ask because you say _This problem has been around for at least a year on multiple Sierra versions_, but macOS Sierra has only been around for about 7 months. This is an important distinction because troubleshooting is a process of elimination and if it's been around only since Sierra, than that eliminates some of the possibilities.

Comment: I am 100% positive for Sierra, but I'm not sure about El Capitan. However, when I look at the timeline it's quite possible it was present on El Capitan as well. Unfortunately, I cannot determine that anymore.

Comment: It's 2023, and it seems this is still precisely the same problem: "It seems that the app that is set to be visible on All Desktops loses focus if you are switching from an app that has been set to some Desktop." ...Did you ever figure it out? /// I've noticed that this is problematic for some apps that only show in the menu bar, and not in the dock. I can't properly select their preference windows in Mission Control; they immediately lose focus. e.g., if I tell the app 24 Hour Wallpaper to show in both places, then the problem goes away. However, not all menu bar apps have this option.